# Getting no albums for a user; facebook PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am beginner with Facebook PHP SDK so please forgive me in advance.
using version: v4.4
I have created a facebook app, filled necessary details. So currently I have basic permissions like public profile. Now I need to fetch user photo albums, so before asking(submitting) facebook for that extended permission I wanted to test my app using test user. Hence I created a test user with user_photo permission, I gave this permission while creating it.

Now here my code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();

$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

var_dump($graphObject);

$albums = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/me/albums'
    );

$responseForAlbums = $albums->execute();
$graphObjectForAlbums = $responseForAlbums->getGraphObject();
echo "<br>dumping albums <br>";
var_dump($graphObjectForAlbums);
```

and as response for last line, I get (blank object):

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)#8 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

What is it that I am missing? Please help.

Suyash

Comment: What is returned for /me Are you using the correct access token?

Comment: @Tobi. Using token means this: FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appid, $secret); ???? 
/me returns public profile of user. Means when i use var_dump($graphObject); from above code I get complete public profile of user

Comment: You cannot use an app access token to request user data other than the Public profile. You need an User access token for that.

Comment: That means in line FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appid, $secret); I'll have to use user access token instead of appid and let secret key be same? if yes then I'll have to fetch different access token for each user everytime. How to do that? 
PS: Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping but I am not getting the point, I am so sorry. Here are my approved permissions https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xxr6je1dz12l19/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-08%20at%201.16.17%20am.png?dl=0        To request user_photos I first need to check my app is working correctly so that I can submit for review. Please help me.